# How to use a string instead of a symbol for `Symbol#to_proc` shorthand

Tags: ruby, symbols, implicit-conversion, proc

```
a = (1..10).to_a
a.map(&:even?)
=> [false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true]
```

How to call map using a string that holds the method name?

```
foo = 'even?'
a.map(...foo...)
```

Comment: The shorthand you mean is called "pretzel colon" :)

Comment: @sawa you edited so much that now the answers provided are not even close to what the OP originally asked.

Comment: @Kyle Yours and Sergio's make sense. In fact, I mistook the question when I first read it, and your answer let me know what was actually asked. Then I edited it to make that clear. It was wrong of the OP to call it "ampersand colon", but that is not crucial. The question is about using the string `foo` in this construction.

Comment: @sawa I am referring to the title, 'instead of a symbol' when all my answer does is convert a string to a symbol... I think it makes it an incorrect answer. Either way, your edits did improve the question but I think the title *could* be different.

Comment: @Kyle Yes. The OP has a string where a symbol should be used, and was asking how to use that string. You showed that it can be converted to a symbol, then be used.

Comment: The question became equivalent to "How to convert symbol into string".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shorthand syntax is not ampersand-colon, it is ampersand followed by a symbol:

```
(1..10).map(& :even?)
```

In Ruby methods are usually referred by symbols, so if you have a symbol in your variable this syntax works as expected:

```
name = :even?
(1..10).map(&name)
```

If you don't have control over the variable method name, e.g. it is an argument, I would recommend using general method `send` instead. It works with both symbols & strings.

```
def perform enum, name
  enum.each{ |e| e.send(name) }
end

perform 1..10, "even?"
```

Comment: My answer became confusing due to question edits, the original question was "How to use ruby shorthand (&: ampersand colon with a variable that holds the method name?"

Comment: Your answer is very helpful and educational.

Answer (score 4):

```
foo = 'even?'
[1,2,3,4,5].map(&foo.to_sym)
 => [false, true, false, true, false]
```

Comment: I'd remove the visual noise from IRB. It's useless.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's useless. It provides the ruby version and also proves the example works. Too many times comments like "it doesn't work for me" flood the comment section and provide even more noise.

Comment: Yes, it does provide ruby version, but that's it. In return it makes it impossible to copy/paste/run the code. In my opinion, it's not worth it :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, it uses "full form" block and is more general.

```
a = (1..10).to_a
name = 'even?'
a.map{|b| b.send name} # => [false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true]
```